# Ionic 4 Loadingcontroller overlay doesnt exist

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I created a simple function of creating a loading like this

```
async presentLoading() {
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Please Wait...',
  });
  await loading.present();
}
```

And i am closing the loader when the data is fetch like this

```
  getUserData(){
  console.log(this.userID);
    this.api.getCompanyEmploye(this.userID).subscribe(res => {
     this.loadingController.dismiss(); //closing here 

      console.log(res);
      this.user = res.records[0];
      this.familyMembers = res.records[0].family_members;
    });
  }
```

I am calling both function in constructor

```
constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController){
  this.presentLoading();
  this.getUserData();
}
```

Its showing error of `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): overlay does not exist`

Answer (score 11):

The issue is that your API call responds sooner than the loading controller gets instantiated. Instead of parallel calls, you should try to serialize those this way:

Make your presentLoading method to return Promise:

```
async presentLoading() {
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Please Wait...',
  });
  return loading.present();
}
```

Now you can call it this way:

```
getUserData(){
  this.presentLoading().then(()=>{
     this.api.getCompanyEmploye(this.userID).subscribe(res => {
        this.loadingController.dismiss(); //closing here 
        console.log(res);
        this.user = res.records[0];
        this.familyMembers = res.records[0].family_members;
    });
  })
}
```

And in your constructor you need only to call for the API

Comment: dono why docs are using async await style..it actually confuses any new comer..haha

Answer (score 0):

for me, the issue is simply because I don't have .catch() for the promise. As@Sergey suggested, this is because the loader is not ready when you calling the ionic loader

```js
this.loadingController.dismiss()
          .then(async () => {
            await this.setStorageForLocalData(data);
          })
          .catch(console.error);
```

where .catch() will dismiss the error